# Select network interface to be used for getting IP information using WMI

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script that finds and displays IP configuration information. I have managed to create the variables to get the information and to display it:

```
$ip = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter "index = '12'").IPAddress[0]

$subnet = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter "index = '12'").IPSubnet[0]

$gateway = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter "index = '12'").DefaultIPGateway

$dns = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter "index = '12'").DNSServerSearchOrder

write-host
write-host

write-host "IP address is: $ip"

write-host "Subnet Mask is: $subnet"

write-host "Default Gateway is: $gateway"

write-host "DNS is: $dns"
```

I'm filtering the interface by index number, which for my case the number is 12 for the right interface. I want to prompt the user with a list of network interfaces. `Get-NetAdapter` command should not be used because it doesn't work on PowerShell v2. The user must be able to see current interfaces including descriptions and be able to select one netowrk adapter interface. The selected interface must be put into a variable i.e. $interface. The variable must output the corresponding adapter index number.  After that, I am able to place the variable in the filter command like: `-Filter "index = '$interfaceindexnumber'"` which should normally display IP information for the selected interface.

Feel free to use a different filter if you believe index number is not the right solution for this case. Please, make sure to use commands that work with PowerShell v2.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of what you are trying to do, which is to allow a user to select an interface that is later used to provide information to you or your script, I took your script and scrubbed it a little bit as well as added in Out-GridView which is great for presenting information to a user. All of these commands should work in PowerShell v2.

I started out by doing just one WMI query and storing it in a variable. Then I pass filtered information to the Out-GridView cmdlet for the user to select whichever interface they want or need to select. I chose to only show the user Description, IPAddress, and Index to prevent too much confusion.

After the user makes the selection, it is assigned to $interface. To extract the full information that was originally queried from win32_networkadapterconfiguration I used the index number of the users selection to filter against $AllNetInterfaces. This could be simplified by just passing all of the information to the Out-GridView to begin with, but again since you plan on having users make selections and such, less is more.

Finally, I call the properties of the object without using the "Write-Host" function because at this point I am validating that it worked and I am not really sure what you are going to do with it later on.

```
$AllNetInterfaces = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Property *

$Interface = $AllNetInterfaces | Select Description, IPAddress, Index | Out-GridView -Title "Available Network Adapters" -OutputMode Single
$Interface = $AllNetInterfaces | ? {$_.Index -match $Interface.Index}

$Interface.IPAddress[0]
$Interface.IPSubnet[0]
$Interface.DefaultIPGateway
$Interface.DNSServerSearchOrder
```

If what you are trying to do is show the user the IP information without using ipconfig, then you could use the Out-GridView cmdlet once again, like this:

```
$Interface | Select IPAddress, IPSubnet, DefaultIPGateway, DNSServerSearchOrder | Out-GridView -Title "IP Info for: $($Interface.Description)"
```

Comment: Thanks David. Your script displays adapter's IP configuration. The grid view is a convenient tool and it allows easy selection. However, like you said above, you were not sure what I was going to do with it later. This was my first step on the script. After getting the information, I wanted to assign it to that interface. I know it is very easy to do with new commands like `New-NetIPAddress` but they are not supported on Windows 7 since it has version 2 by default. Do you know any way to set a static IP on version 2 of powershell?

Comment: You should check out the methods that are available within win32_networkadapterconfiguration pretty useful stuff. I'm mobile right now otherwise I'd be more helpful I think. Here is a link to msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oops my phone cut me off. Here is a link to the scripting guys blog to demonstrate use. Hope that is helpful! https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings/

Comment: Btw., the solution to my question above was easier than I thought. I'm sure you will understnad what I mean:

    `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration | Select Index, @{n="IP"; e={$_.ipaddress[0]}}, @{n="Subnet"; e={$_.IPSubnet[0]}}, Description | Format-Table -AutoSize`

`[int]$ifindex = Read-Host "Select Network Adapter by Index Number"`

Comment: That's great Jeff, I'm glad you found something that works for your use case!

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration | Select Index, @{n="IP"; e={$_.ipaddress[0]}}, @{n="Subnet"; e={$_.IPSubnet[0]}}, Description | Format-Table -AutoSize
[int]$ifindex = Read-Host "Select Network Adapter by Index Number"

$adapters = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter "index = '$ifindex'"

foreach ($adapter in $adapters){
$ip = $adapter.IPAddress[0]
$subnet = $adapter.IPSubnet[0]
$gateway = $adapter.DefaultIPGateway 
$dns = $adapter.DNSServerSearchOrder   
}

$ip
$subnet
$gateway
$dns
```